# How can I format a specific type of citation (notecite) to print in a smaller font size than the default (12pt)?

Tags: biblatex, citing, fontsize

I am using a lot of abbreviated citation notes in my text and to have a list of them I'm using biblatex and `\notecite` with shorthand abbreviations in the style `ABBREVIATION`+`example.code`. This is going well, but I would like the citations (or technically citation prenote and postnote) to be smaller since in the text where there are a lot of them they tend to overpower the actual examples and text. What I would like is a way to define the `\notecite` to appear smaller like in this example:
[image: notecite examples]

I used `\footnotesize` with each `\notecite` in the minimal working example to get the effect I want, but using this for each one gets very tedious since these abbreviated citation notes number in the hundreds.
This is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\begin{filecontents}{citelist.bib}

@book{REF,
    shorthand = {REF},
    pagination={none},
    year={1986},
    title = {Ensk-íslensk skólaorðabók},
    editor = {{Jón Skaptason}},
    publisher = {Örn og Örlygur},
    location = {Reykjavík}
    }  

@book{LUC,
    shorthand = {LUC},
    pagination={none},
    address = {Cambridge},
    year = {1997},
    booktitle = {Color Categories in Thought and Language},
    author = {John A. Lucy},
    location = {Cambridge}
    }
}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[LY1,T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\usepackage[sortlocale=auto,backend=biber,style=authoryear,sorting=nyt,abbreviate=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{citelist.bib}


\begin{document}

normal: \\

For example \notecite[REF][f.1249.54]{REF}, (and also \notecite[LUC][f.16.235]{LUC}). \\

With footnotesize: \\

For example {\footnotesize\notecite[REF][f.1249.54]{REF}}, (and also {\footnotesize\notecite[LUC][f.16.235]{LUC}}). 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the definition of `\notecite` in `biblatex.def` ([ll. 2218-2223](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/e5d6e69e61613cc33ab1fcc2083a8277eb9cfce5/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L2218-L2223) in v3.15a). To make the output of that command smaller we can add a wrapper command with the optional argument that sets the font size to `\footnotesize`. No other citation commands are affected.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[LY1,T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, abbreviate=true]{biblatex}

\newcommand*{\mkbibfootnotesize}[1]{{\footnotesize #1}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\notecite}[\mkbibfootnotesize]
  {\printfield{prenote}%
   \setunit*{\printdelim{prenotedelim}}}
  {\nocite{\thefield{entrykey}}}
  {}
  {\printfield{postnote}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{REF,
  shorthand  = {REF},
  pagination = {none},
  year       = {1986},
  title      = {Ensk-íslensk skólaorðabók},
  editor     = {{Jón Skaptason}},
  publisher  = {Örn og Örlygur},
  location   = {Reykjavík},
}  
@book{LUC,
  shorthand  = {LUC},
  pagination = {none},
  address    = {Cambridge},
  year       = {1997},
  booktitle  = {Color Categories in Thought and Language},
  author     = {John A. Lucy},
  location   = {Cambridge},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
For example \notecite[REF][f.1249.54]{REF}, (and also \notecite[LUC][f.16.235]{LUC})

With footnotesize:

For example {\footnotesize\notecite[REF][f.1249.54]{REF}}, (and also {\footnotesize\notecite[LUC][f.16.235]{LUC}}). 

\end{document}
```

[image: Notecite in footnotesize]